# Need to delete/insert that corresponding row in that table, as there is duplicate data coming up- PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I need a help in getting the PLSQL procedure to : Insert/Delete the rows of a table , because as I used Update functionality getting duplicates for that particular Sequence ID field.

So for a particular sequence ID row, whenever I insert the data, it should be the latest in that table.

Answer (score 0):

The last sentence you wrote suggests that you have to

- delete row(s) whose ID equals that particular "sequence ID" value
- then insert a new row

If you expected some code to be written, you should have posted some more info (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, as well as the way you manipulate it by inserting new row, showing what you expect to happen with old one(s)). It is difficult to write code based on unknown data model.

Comment: Yes I have the procedure I am using currently.

Answer (score 0):

A guess...

```
INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name(
    primary_key_column
,   other_column
)
VALUES(
    (SELECT max(primary_key_column)+1 FROM schema_name.table_name),
,   'other_value'
);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure I am using:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eGbxSppjexpICKh6pzuW0ZzckVxA6BB0/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QlyD.png)[image: Data for the table]

[image: Table:]

My requirement when we need to insert the new data , the previous data should be deleted for the corresponding ID.

In the above procedure I am updating the data.